# Cleaning dataframe- assign value in one cell to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading multiple CSV files from a folder into a dataframe. I loop for all the files in the folder and then concat the dataframes to obtain the final dataframe. 
However the CSV file has one summary row from which I want to extract the date, and then add as a new column for all the rows in that csv/dataframe.

'''

```
df=pd.read_csv(f,header=None,names=['Inverter',"Day Yield",'month Yield','Year Yield','SpecificYieldDay','SYMth','SYYear','Power'],sep=';', **kwargs)
df['date']=df.loc[[0],['Day Yield']]
df
```

I expect ['date'] column to be filled with the date for that file for all the rows in that particular csv, but it gets filled correctly only for the first row.

[Refer to image of dataframe. I want all the rows of the 'date' column to be showing 7/25/2019 instead of only the first row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XDYL.png)

I have also added an example of one of the csv files I am reading from
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbTwQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the value that you want to add as a new column for all rows is in `df.loc[[0],['Day Yield']]`.

If that is correct you can do the following:

`df = df.assign(date=[df.loc[[0],['Day Yield']]]*len(df))`

Comment: Hi, yes, thank you. This works. Why does it fail if I remove "*len(df)" ?  
- usually don't put this when i use df.assign

Comment: Hi Holden, that's because when you multiply a list in python by x, it just gets repeated x times. Therefore by multiplying `[df.loc[[0],['Day Yield']]]` (which is a list with a single value) by `len(df)` we create a list with the length of our `df`. This is exactly what we want to assign to the column `date`